# Disappearing watchOS complication

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

I spent some time studying how to make my first watchOS Complication. At first I couldn't make it work at all, I kept trying and I got some results finally. However my Complication works only for a brief moment and then reset itself to the default placeholder.

[image: Apple Watch Screenshot 1]
[image: Apple Watch Screenshot 2. Notifications has 2 actions]
[image: Apple Watch Screenshot 3.]
[image: Apple Watch Screenshot 4.]

First screenshot shows what happens when you force touch Watch Face. Second is a very brief moment after pressing command + shift + H. The third screenshot shows default placeholder and it appears with the following log message:

> Extension received request to wake up for complication support.

The last screenshot is when you scroll through complications list.

I am using standard `ComplicationController.swift` template. Only thing I customised is this method:

```
func getPlaceholderTemplateForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {

    let tmpl = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()

    let drop = UIImage(named: "drop")
    tmpl.headerImageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: drop!)

    tmpl.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Drink water")
    tmpl.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Hidrating helps to stay helthy")

    handler(tmpl)
}
```

iOS app is written on Objective-C and Apple Watch app and extension — Swift.

If you having troubles making your complication work, go through this list.

1. Data Source Class needs `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).` prefix. Look at the Xcode screenshot below.
2. Only enable Supported Families for complications that you supporting.
3. Project > Build Settings > Packaging > Defines Modules should should be set to `YES`.
4. Project > Build Settings > Search Paths > Always Search User Paths should be set to `NO`.
5. Make sure class `ComplicationController` conforms to the `CLKComplicationDataSource` protocol. For some reason my template didn't have it.
6. Your complication images need to be in [correct size.](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/)
7. Only select green Complication target before running your project.
8. Reset Content and Settings for both simulators.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

What am I missing? Why my Complication disappears in the Simulator and don't appear on real hardware at all?